Return the entries that occured right before a given time in SQL
I have a table which contains surgery times of patients. I would like to return the blood pressure values of the patients right before the surgery time within max 24 hours in the past.



Patient ID
Surgerytime
Blood Pressure time
Value




100
2010-04-26T13:01:00
2010-04-25T15:01:00
80


100
2010-04-26T13:01:00
2010-04-26T07:30:00
120


100
2010-04-26T13:01:00
2010-04-26T08:10:00
85


100
2010-04-26T13:01:00
2010-04-26T12:00:00
110



The table I would like to have such that we only return the blood pressure value of the patient right before the surgery is below:



Patient ID
Surgerytime
Blood Pressure time
Value




100
2010-04-26T13:01:00
2010-04-26T12:00:00
110




Please show us what you tried, and explain where you are stuck - doesn't seem difficult.

Hint: DATEADD

Your table is badly denormalized. But you can try something like: select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by [Patient ID], SurgeryTime order by [Blood Pressure time] DESC) sort from yourtable t where [Blood pressure time] <= surgeryTime) x where x.sort = 1 This assumes blood pressure is not taken after surgery. The other requirement is left as exercise to the reader

Seems of you take the learnings from your previous questions you'd have all you need.

Have you even tried anything???

I tried this filter:
bloodpressuretime  >= DATEADD(HOUR , -1 , surgerytime) and bloodpressuretime <= surgerytime.
This gives me all the entries of blood pressure that happened within an hour before the surgery time. But the problem with this method again is that I get many entries , not just the last blood pressure before the surgerytime but everything that happened in the last 1 hour of surgerytime.

The output from this method gives me bloodpressuretimes 2018-03-12 04:09:58,
2018-03-12 04:15:30, 2018-03-12 04:20:00 for the surgerytime 2018-03-12 04:30:00. So in principle I just want the blood pressure 2018-03-12 04:20:00 which is the one that was measured right before the surgery. So I am still looking for an answer.

You could partition by the patient ID and surgery time, and take only the latest one. You can then further filter and take only surgeries that happened in the last 24 hours:
SELECT Patient_ID, Surgerytime, Blood_Pressure_time, Value
FROM   (SELECT Patient_ID, Surgerytime, Blood_Pressure_time, Value,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_ID, Surgerytime
                                  ORDER BY Blood_Pressure_time DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  Surgerytime > Blood_Pressure_time -- Exclude post-op measurements
               AND
               DATEDIFF(HOUR, Surgerytime, NOW()) < 24 -- Only in the last day
       )
WHERE  rn = 1


DATEDIFF(HOUR, Surgerytime, NOW()) isn't SARGable, and NOW() isn't a SQL Server function anyway. It can be replaced with SurgeryTime>=dateadd(hour,-24,getdate())

The comment about changing the 24 hour test is accurate, as is the suggestion to improve it. But otherwise this approach is MUCH better than the other answers.

I have tried the filter
bloodpressuretime  >= DATEADD(HOUR , -24 , Surgerytime) and bloodpressuretime <= Surgerytime
But the problem with the filter is that it gives me all the entries of blood pressure that happened in the last 24 hours of Surgery time. And since blood pressure is a time series data , the entries are many. While I am just looking to return one entry of blood pressure that was measured right before the sugery time.

That's where the row_number condition comes in to play

You can do it with a LEFT JOIN that searches for a newer measurement than the last measurement candidate to discard any measurement that has a newer match.
SELECT last_measure.[Patient ID], last_measure.Surgerytime, last_measure.[Blood Pressure time], last_measure.[Value]
FROM yourtable last_measure
LEFT JOIN yourtable even_newer
ON last_measure.[Patient ID] = even_newer.[Patient ID] and last_measure.[Blood Pressure time] < even_newer.[Blood Pressure time] AND even_newer.[Blood Pressure time] < last_measure.Surgerytime
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Surgerytime) >= [Blood Pressure time] AND
      even_newer.[Patient ID] IS NULL

Explanation:

we query yourtable and alias it to last_measure, any record's last_measure must be a valid last measurement before surgery
we LEFT JOIN with yourtable aliased as even_newer just to disprove there is no newer measurement than the last one, we search for newer measurements via [Patient ID] and [Blood Pressure time] matching
we discard any measurement that was done more than a day earlier than the Surgerytime even if it was the last measurement of the patient
we also check for even_newer being before the Surgerytime of last_measure, because if the patient had a surgery and had his/her blood pressure measured afterwards, then we discard this "afterwards" for the surgery of last_measure
and of course, we check for even_newer.[Patient ID] being NULL to make sure that we have no newer measurement for the patient than the last one
finally, we reap the fruits of our effort by actually selecting the fields we are interested about


This will work, but a window function approach will be far more efficient.

Please see example select below in the link
https://dbfiddle.uk/sfXzlXNj
I have added patient 200 to the data who has had 2 surgeries and tested with the 2 patients in SQL Server.
Here is the code including the table,
Create table Patient (PatientId int, SurgeryTime char(100), BPTime char(100), BPVal int);
insert into Patient (PatientId, SurgeryTime, BPTime, BPVal) values 
(100,'2010-04-26T13:01:00','2010-04-25T15:01:00',80), 
(100,'2010-04-26T13:01:00','2010-04-26T07:30:00',120),
(100,'2010-04-26T13:01:00','2010-04-26T08:10:00',85),
(100,'2010-04-26T13:01:00','2010-04-26T12:00:00',110),  
(200,'2010-07-27T14:01:00','2010-07-24T12:00:00',111),
(200,'2010-07-27T14:01:00','2010-07-26T12:00:00',135),
(200,'2010-09-29T14:01:00','2010-07-27T12:00:00',143),
(200,'2010-09-29T14:01:00','2010-07-28T12:00:00',150);

select 
  f1.* 
  --f1.PatientId , f1.SurgeryTime, f1.BPVal, max(f1.BPTime)
  from 
Patient f1
  join patient f2
  on f1.PatientId=f2.PatientId
  and f1.SurgeryTime = f2.SurgeryTime
  and f1.SurgeryTime > f2.BPTime
  and f1.BPTime >= f2.BPTime
  where 
    (f2.BPTime = ( select max(RR.BPTime) from Patient RR where f2.PatientId=RR.PatientId 
  and f2.SurgeryTime=RR.SurgeryTime))
  order by f1.PatientId
  ;

